# Android Google Text-to-Speech Engine: Installing Voices with no Internet connectivity

Tags: android, text-to-speech, sideloading

I have an Android application that's used on wearable devices in an industrial environment. It uses text-to-speech extensively.

The devices are connected to a WiFi network which, by design and necessity, has no connection to the Internet. Software and configuration are provisioned via an MDM suite (SOTI, AirWatch or similar). At the moment, we're deploying the Google Text-to-Speech engine as an APK. This works great for US English.

We're looking at adding support for additional languages, starting with Spanish. Spanish voices do not come bundled with the engine.

I know it is possible to download new voices via Settings -> Accessibility -> Text-to-speech output, if the device is connected to the Internet.

Is there a way to "sideload" additional voices without having an Internet connection? Alternatively, is there a way to obtain (or generate) a Google Text-to-Speech Engine APK which has specific additional voices baked in?

Comment: There must be a way since the Google TTS comes preinstalled in different countries with different languages.